# Arrayfire Bessel Functions

Tags: c++, arrayfire, bessel-functions

I am trying to understand the syntax of the bessel functions defined in the arrayfire documentation provided here:  http://archive.arrayfire.com/arrayfire/c/group__image__func__c__bessel.htm#gaa625037807cb75ef8815051c066e9657

Under the section for  af_besselj_C, I am uncertain what this "nu" term is.  I understand the out and in arrays, and I believe the "n" is for the order of the bessel function.  Does anyone know what this "nu" term represents?  Thanks!

Comment: A friendly reminder that Bessel functions are in the [standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric), and that you should read [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to tell [based on the documentation](http://archive.arrayfire.com/arrayfire/c/group__image__func__c__bessel.htm), but it looks like the `unsigned n` value is probably the input/output array size, while the `nu` is the actual subscript `n` for `J_n(z)`. The documentation has the example

```
float ha[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
array a   = array(5, 1, ha);
array out = array(5, 1, f32);
float* p_in  =   a.device<float>();
float* p_out = out.device<float>();
// Modified first kind
af_besseli_S(p_out, 5, p_in, 2.0);
```